# Firebase authentication in Flutter application using SignInWithEmailAndPassword takes a lot of time

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

After pressing the login button, nothing happens for a long time, the login is performed after 10 seconds or 1 minute.I checked the application for about a week and before everything worked instantly.The problem appeared a week after I last opened the application. A very long answer from Firebase.The problem exists both on the real device and in the emulator.
It works a little faster on the emulator.

Authorization method

```
class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _fauth;
  AuthMethods(this._fauth);

User get user =>_fauth.currentUser!;

 //State authUser?
 Stream<User?> get authState=>FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(); 
//Sign In

  Future<void> signInWithEmail({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    try {
      await _fauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      if (!_fauth.currentUser!.emailVerified) {
        await sendVerification(context);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showErrorSnackBar(context, e.message!);
    }
  }
```

Widget with a call to the authorization method at the click of a button

```
class __FormWidgState extends State<_FormWidg> {
  final TextEditingController _logController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passController = new TextEditingController();

  void _authent() async {
    context.read<AuthMethods>().signInWithEmail(
        email: _logController.text,
        password: _passController.text,
        context: context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authErr = this.authErr;
 return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "Username",
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _logController,
          ),
          Text(
            "Password",
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _passController,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _authent,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Log In",
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushNamed(context,"/registration"),
                child: Text("Registration"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
Future <void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers:[
      Provider<AuthMethods>(create: (_)=>AuthMethods(FirebaseAuth.instance),),
      StreamProvider(
        create:(context)=>context.read<AuthMethods>().authState,
        initialData: null,
      ),
    ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
         
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const AuthWrap(),
        
        routes :{
         
           '/auth':(context) => AuthWidg(),
          "/registration":(context) => RegistrWidg(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

  
class AuthWrap extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthWrap({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final fireuser = context.watch<User?>();
   if (fireuser!=null) {
    
    return const mainScreen();
    
    }
      return const AuthWidg();
   }
  }
```